# Assembly x86: I have to program the Ackermann function

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to program the Ackermann function. This is what I have so far:

```
    .model small
;
    extrn   putstrng:far
    extrn   newline:far
    extrn   getdec$:far
    extrn   putdec$:far
; 
;
    .stack 1024                  
;
    .const


    .data

    .code
    assume ds:dgroup
;
debut:  mov     ax, seg dgroup     
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax
;

    mov     ax,2   ; value of N
    mov     bx,ax
    mov     ax,2 ; Value of M
    mov     dx,ax
    mov     cx,0

    push    dx
    push    bx

    call ackermann

    pop     bx
    pop     dx

    MOV ax, 0
    MOV ax, cx
call    putdec$
call    newline


    mov     ax, 4c00h          
    int     21h

ackermann   proc far C uses cx

    mov dx, [bp+6] 
    mov bx, [bp+4]
    cmp bx, 0
    JE firstCase
    cmp dx, 0
    JE secondCase
    dec dx
    push dx
    push bx
    CALL ackermann
    pop bx
    pop dx
    dec bx
    push dx
    push bx
    CALL ackermann
    pop bx
    pop dx
    ret


firstCase:
    MOV cx, dx
    inc cx
    ret


secondCase:
    DEC bx
    push dx
    push bx
    call ackermann
    pop bx
    pop dx
    ret

ackermann endp

    end     debut
```

---

Whatever I put for the value of N or M, i always get the answer 0. I think I know why. This part :

```
MOV ax, 0
MOV ax, cx
call    putdec$
call    newline
```

is probably wrong, but I don't know what to do with it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your Ackermann function actually *works* and leaves its result in the `cx` register, and that `putdec$` prints the value in the `ax` register, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that code segment you've shown.

It needlessly loads zero into `ax` first but then replaces it with `cx`.

Hence your problem lies with one of:

- `putdec$` does not print `ax`.
- your Ackermann function does not work as you expect.
- your Ackermann function does not return its value in `cx`.

Fist step is to fire up your debugger and set a breakpoint at the `mov ax, 0` instruction - this will tell you what value is in `cx` (and other registers) to check whether the Ackermann function is working.

Then you may need to go back and single-step through the function, comparing it to what you expect to happen at each stage with some paper and pencils.

---

With a bit of static code analysis, and a quick investigation into what this Ackermann function actually is meant to do :-) , I can discern the following:

One thing I'm not sure you have right (if you're using the Wikipedia definition of the Ackermann function [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)) is the second case. It states that:

```
         /  n + 1             if m = 0
A(m,n) = |  A(m-1,1)          if m > 0 and n = 0
         \  A(m-1,A(m,n-1))   if m > 0 and n > 0
```

Your second case code decrements `bx/m` as expected but leaves `dx/n` alone, rather than setting it to one.

In your third case (though I haven't looked closely) you do call the function twice but nowehere can I see a transfer of `cx`, the result of the first, inner `A()` call, to either one of the registers pushed onto the stack for the outer call. This would be a vital step in calculating a nested function like `A(x,A(y,z))`.

Instead, your outer call seems to use some variation of the *original* values.

Those two helpful pointers should be a good start for you, to hone your debugging skills and become a better developer :-)